# Deploy Farm Solutions to Online SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, office-365, visual-web-part, farm-solution, visual-studio-2013

I am migrating SharePoint 2010 project to online SharePoint 2013. I managed to move lists, document libraries..etc. with sandbox solutions.

But can any one help me how can I deploy the farm solutions?

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint Online you can not use Farm solutions! You are limited to sandboxed solutions and Apps.

You would have to rewrite and rearchitect your solutions to one of those two patterns.

For sandboxed solutions, see here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg454741(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg454741%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
(Please note that sandboxed solutions, that are not no-code solutions, are deprecated: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx)

For apps, see here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163114(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163114%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Added to Robert, you can check the below link for App approaches to the common customization which we do in SharePoint http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/07/16/app-approaches-to-common-sharepoint-customizations.aspx. Microsoft developed a codeplex solution https://officeams.codeplex.com/ for App model samples which you can leverage while converting your SharePoint customizations to Apps.